# Сортировка четных и нечётных чисел в массиве по возрастанию и убыванию

Tags: c++, сортировка, динамические-массивы

Доброго времени суток всем!
Нужно в введённом пользователем массиве отсортировать числа так, чтобы сначала шли чётные числа по возрастанию, а за ними нечётные по убыванию. Входные числа должны быть от 2 до 10000.
Проблема такова:
Если ввести первое число нечётное, то оно так и будет на выходе стоять первым( хотя должно быть чётное ). Вторым числом зачастую ставится ноль. 
В общем, проблема состоит в первых двух числах на выходе.
`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n;
    tryAgain:
    cout <<"Введите число от 2 до 10000"<<endl; cin >> n;
if(n>=2 && n<=10000){
    int *arr=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    for (int i=n; i>0; i--)    
        for (int j=n; j>1; j--)
            if(arr[j]%2==0 && arr[j-1]!=0)
                swap(arr[j], arr[j-1]);
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<arr[i];
    cout<<endl;         

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++)
            if(arr[j]%2!=0 && arr[j+1]%2!=0){           
                if(arr[j]<arr[j+1])
                    swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]);

            }else if((arr[j]%2==0 || arr[j]==0) && (arr[j+1]%2==0 || arr[j+1]==0))
                if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
                    swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]);
    cout<<endl;     
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";


} else goto tryAgain;
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: А каков ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

А если воспользоваться `sort` [с соответствующим компаратором](https://ideone.com/3zFoZ0)?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool comp(int l, int r)
{
    if (l%2 < r%2) return true;
    if (l%2 > r%2) return false;
    if (l%2 == 0 && r%2 == 0) return l < r;
    if (l%2 == 1 && r%2 == 1) return l > r;
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 400 ; ++i)
        v.push_back(rand()%10000);

    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),comp);

    for(auto i: v) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
}
```

Если самому надо писать - опять же, воспользуйтесь этим компаратором и не мучьтесь...